# Slick.js centerMode не работает в Сафари

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Если включить слайдеру centerMode: true, то слайдер становится неровным в Сафари (слайды уходят влево). Но ровным (по центру)в хроме. Если отключить - идеально в Сафари, и плохо в Хроме. Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась с помощью обнуления маржинов для .slick-list.